Migrating a web site from shared cPanel to unmanaged Ubuntu 22.04 vps and not able to successfully import an sql file
I got an unmanaged VPS from Hostinger a week ago and am trying to host a few web sites on the server. I have to say here that I am quite new to Ubuntu 22.04 with FASTPANEL.
I have migrated the files and databases from the old server to this new one, except one sql file. The specifications of the old server are:

I tried to import this sql file of one of the web sites into phpMyAdmin without success. I believe it is not because of the size of the file. I had successfully imported a larger file of an almost identical site (in a different language). The specifications of the new server are:

The error thrown by phpMyAdmin when importing is:
Error
Static analysis:
2 errors were found during analysis.
A symbol name was expected! (near ")" at position 206) At least one column definition was expected. (near ")" at position 206) SQL query: Copy
-- -------------------------------------------------------- -- -- Stand-in structure for view m6K_wsm_dateWiseBounceRate -- (See below for the actual view) -- CREATE TABLE m6K_wsm_dateWiseBounceRate ( );
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 8
I believe there are no errors at the above specified lines.
I also tried to import it via Hostinger browser terminal:
cd /var/www/fastuser/data/www/en.beentee.net

mysql -u beentee -f -p enbeentee < mgls_enbeent.sql

The error thrown by the Hostinger browser terminal is:

I even tried to create an upload folder for phpMyAdmin with the following commands though I still do not know if the file can be imported this way:
sudo find / -type d  -name phpmyadmin

mkdir -p /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/upload
mkdir -p /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/save
chmod a+w /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/upload
chmod a+w /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/save

gedit /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

cd /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin
sudo nano config.inc.php

But the last two commands did not work:
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/upload';

$cfg['SaveDir'] = '/usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/save';

Please help me solve this problem.
